# Cross-platform way to invoke Python 3.x command

Tags: python, windows, linux, macos, command-line

`python` command is generally mapped to the latest Python 2.x compiler across different operating systems. However, are there yet such standard way to invoke Python 3.x interpreter (any or the latest version installed)?

... so one could run your Python 3.x compatible script as:

```
 python3 yourscript.py
```

As a bonus, if there also exists a cross-platform way to invoke virtualenv command to create a local installation for Python 3?

- Ubuntu seems to provide python3 command, does not seem to provide virtualenv for Python 3.x as prepackaged
- OSX (Macports, BSD?) prefer python-3.2, python-3.1 commands, provides virtualenv-3.2, virtualenv-3.1

Currently I am trying to have some trial-and-error heuristics to get things done

- https://github.com/miohtama/vvv/blob/master/vvv/sysdeps.py#L80

Comment: On Ubuntu, you can do `virtualenv -p python3 mypy3venv` to make a virtualenv. The `-p` option should work on any platform, but I think it still depends on the name of the Python 3 executable.

Comment: On Windows, `python` is the default name for *all* versions of Python, 3.x too.

Comment: @ThomasK unfortunately it does not work on at least Ubuntu 10.04 [~]# uname -a
Linux Ubuntu-1004-lucid-64-minimal 2.6.32-39-server #86-Ubuntu SMP                                                       
[~]# virtualenv -p python3 mypy3venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/virtualenv.py", line 16
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: I guess the version of virtualenv in 10.04 is too old. You need at least version 1.6, I think, for Python 3.

Comment: ThomasK: I am using these instructions to work around the matter http://miohtama.github.com/vvv/installation.html#installing-locally-using-virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [PEP 394 The "python" Command on Unix-Like Systems](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) and [PEP 397 Python launcher for Windows](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) I guess your best option is to use `#! /usr/bin/python3` shebang in your script and direct Windows users to install and use *Python launcher* (`py` command) instead of `python` command.

Answer (score 1):

There is no complete solution for this. Python3 may not be installed on the client. What would you do then? You might start by checking for the Python version when the script executes.

```
print sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

If the executing Python is not Python3, then you can ask the user to either install it or invoke your script with the Python3 interpreter, etc. You might decide to just fail to run at all when the user invokes your script with Python2. There are many ways (FAQs, System Requirements, etc.) to inform users that the script requires Python3 and then let them deal with that problem rather than you trying to do so in code.

I've seen this done in the Microsoft .Net runtime. When the user does not have the required version of .Net, the program asks the user to install it before proceeding and points them to a URL.

One other suggestion, on Linux systems, you can prefer Python3 (if it is installed) by adding this to the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Of course, you'd have to know for sure that path exists. You might alos use `env` to do this in a more flexible manner.